# Semaphore output is wrong

Tags: python, multiprocessing, semaphore

I'm trying to get semaphores working in python but for some reason they won't work like I want them to.
I would like them to print one number at a time like:

```
sem1: 1
wait
sem2: 2
wait
sem1: 3
wait
sem2: 4
```

but the output is like:

```
sem1: 1
sem2: 2
wait
sem1: 3
sem2: 4
```

this is my code:

```
import os, multiprocessing, time

sem1 = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)
sem2 = multiprocessing.Semaphore(0)

pid1 = os.fork()
pid2 = -1

if pid1 != 0:
    pid2 = os.fork()
for i in range(1,20):
    if (i%2) == 1 and pid1==0:
            sem1.acquire()
            print("sem1: %d" %i)
            sem2.release()
            time.sleep(1)
    elif (i%2) == 0 and pid2==0:
            sem2.acquire()
            print("sem2: %d" %i)
            sem1.release()
            time.sleep(1)
```

Am I making a mistake in my thinking?

Comment: don't they wait together? like the `time.sleep` will only make the one process sleep so they will both do their first step then wait, then both do their second step then wait....

Comment: Why are you using `os.fork`? Shouldn't you use the `multiprocessing` module's facilities for creating processes? The documentation doesn't say anything about how the `multiprocessing` module interacts with manual forks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`time.sleep()` needs to be called from parent process to achieve the functionality. Following is the modified code, I believe this is how you want:

```
import os, multiprocessing, time

sem1 = multiprocessing.Semaphore(1)
sem2 = multiprocessing.Semaphore(0)

pid1 = os.fork()
pid2 = -1

if pid1 != 0:
    pid2 = os.fork()
for i in range(1,20):
    time.sleep(1)
    if (i%2) == 1 and pid1==0:
            sem1.acquire()
            print("sem1: %d" %i)
            sem2.release()
            #time.sleep(1)
    elif (i%2) == 0 and pid2==0:
            sem2.acquire()
            print("sem2: %d" %i)
            sem1.release()
            #time.sleep(1)
```

Output:

sem1: 1

wait

sem2: 2

wait

sem1: 3

wait

sem2: 4

wait

Reasoning:

When you are using the `time.sleep(1)` for the individual child process, only that child process sleeps not the parent process. When `i` is odd, it(corresponding child process) prints and goes to sleep but the parent process is still active and executes the child process when `i` is even. When `i` increaments and goes to even again it waits until the sleep cycle is completed. When we call `thread.sleep(1)` in the parent, it waits for each `i` value.

Comment: Thanks! Instead of putting it in the beginning of the loop I put it at the en so it will print first and then wait

Comment: Alright, you need to call it from parent process that's the key.